# Android WifiP2PService java.IllegalArgumentException : Null device causing phone to randomly reboot

Tags: java, android, wifip2p

I am using Android WifiP2P service to make a group connection between 10 phones with one being the Host and others being Guests. I coded everything and it seems to be working fine when I test on API<=22, but on API 23 and higher I randomly get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WifiP2pService
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null device
```

The error occurs with no apparent trigger, and it happens randomly. Sometimes phones are able to communicate with no issues for almost 30 minutes, but sometimes it happens a couple of times in just a few minutes.

I am not sure what might be causing this. I would be very grateful if someone finds time and knowledge to help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

This is a screenshot of the error.

[image: This is a screenshot of the error]

Comment: I cannot see image because of my system configuration but did you encapsulate your code with try catch? Also you could check if the variable is not null before assigning it. Is it already your case?

Comment: Yes, everything is already within the try catch. I am confused here because the error is pointing to the system library, not a single part of my code is pointed at.

Comment: No values are null as well.